# Which analogs of Newton's multivariate method are faster?

Tags: nonlinear-equations, numerical-modelling, newton-method

Currently, I am studying a 2D nonlinear Schroedinger equation and searching for the fastest method.
$$
\begin{equation}
i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = [-\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2  + V_0(r) - i\gamma  + g|\psi|^2]\psi + \Phi(r,t),
\end{equation}
$$
Studying the amplitude of the solution to this time-dependent equation I decided to split the $\psi$ function into two independent functions of time and coordinate:
$$
\begin{equation}
\psi = u(r)e^{-i\varepsilon t},
\Phi(r,t) = A(r)e^{-i\varepsilon t}
\end{equation}
$$
This simplification speeds up the solution program because I no longer need to simulate the evolution of the system and just observe the final result at the stationary regime. Then I obtain such equation:
$$
\begin{equation}
[-\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2  + V_0(r) - i\gamma - \varepsilon + g|\psi|^2]\psi + A(r) = 0
\end{equation}
$$

I use Newton's method to find the solution (note that $r$ stands for $(x,y)$). Because of the 2D problem, I discretize the domain in 1024x1024 vertices. This leads to a problem of inversing (1024*1024)x(1024*1024) matrix. This task doesn't allow me to use GPU because I have low memory resources and I can't parallelise it with CPU.

At this moment a MATLAB code I have created takes way too much time (up to $2500$ seconds to converge to accuracy $10^{-9}$). So I wonder if there is a faster method I could implement to achieve the same accuracy within a smaller time.

Comment: I split my u(x,y) function on real and complex parts and using multivariate Newton's method

Comment: Are you storing a dense or a sparse matrix?

Comment: Newton-GMRES with a proper matrix-free implementation would likely perform the best on a problem of this size

Comment: How does the error develop as you do more Newton iterations? How do you compute the initial guess? Can you solve the problem on a coarser grid, extrapolate the solution to the fine grid and then polish it off with a single Newton step? Why is a parallel linear solve not possible in this context?

Comment: @DanielShapero I store sparse matrix

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you very much, will read about it

Comment: @CarlChristian
1) It dependes on initial guess. I calculate spectrum, so I change epsilon between using Newton's method. So for the first epsilon method needs 7 iterations to converge. Further steps need just 3 iterations because of better initial guess.
2) Haven't thought of it, maybe this is good solution. But haven't done extrapolation before.
3) On a coarser grid I will be able to parallelise my task on CPU. Even though I doubt that GPU will handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looking for a better method it's probably worth trying a faster programming language. If you do this in Julia (or C++/Fortran) you would likely see a significant speedup. Julia would be especially nice since there is a lot of libraries for doing matrix free solves.

Comment: Speed up depends on if OP is using a MATLAB function that is really just a wrapper to a lower level language library or if OP is running pure MATLAB code with for loops.